# (Python) dash core components - ModuleNotFound

Tags: python, plotly-dash

)
When I want to import dash_core_components

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
```

it throws the following error:

```
File "d:\Desktop\python_projekte\ds2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import dash_core_components as dcc
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\dash_core_components\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from dash.dcc import *  # noqa: F401, F403, E402
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dash.dcc'
```

But I acually installed dash_core_components and I also tried updating it, but I still receive this error. I've got also a similar error with dash_html_components.

I really don't know what to do. Does someone have an advice? :-)

Comment: Maybe look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/69142985/9098350, looks similar.

Comment: You may need to reinstall or upgrade dash `pip install -U dash` or if you are using environments to manage packages, double check you have dash installed in the environment you're using or that you have the correct environment activated.

Answer (score 14):

For people coming across this issue in 2022, the syntax of:

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
```

has been deprecated. Use this syntax instead:

```
from dash import dcc
from dash input html
```

Answer (score 1):

Same for `import dash_html_components as html`.

Use `from dash import html`

Comment: What do you mean by "same"? Same as what? You are aware that there is no predictable order of posts on StackOverflow, aren't you? It is individually configurable.

Comment: This should probably be edited into the previous answer so that both aspects of the question are answered in one post.

Comment: Sorry, not enough reputation to comment.

Comment: I combined the two responses. Good idea.